# Sorting Win Form CheckListbox

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

When the user right clicks a DataGridView cell in my windows application it clears and fills the CheckedListBox with column header text. Then it shows a popup. Now how can I sort the items using what is checked? I want to sort on the same right click.

Comment: Here on SO questions are expected to show research and effort put forth into the problem before answers are provided. Perhaps you would like to research the problem further and post a specific question on why your attempt at resolving the issue does not work.

Comment: i add code under DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs.When i click the cell origin it adds already checked items to the grid.After search i posted this question.I am just beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort the listbox, you need to write your own small code, which "tells" the program how to sort your data.

Please refer this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort.aspx)

Comment: i want to sort items in checked list box not the datagridview

Comment: @nalini: Please see the new answer